# Need to load static content in JMETER tests

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to figure out a way to load content from a file containing list of ids in the preprocessing step in Jmeter. This needs to happen only once and not every time for each request. So it should be like -

1. Load all the list of static ids from the file once.
2. For every request pick one id randomly from this list.
3. POST the request

I am trying to explore JSR223 preprocessor but not much luck so far. Also I am not sure whether the preprocessor executes for every request which I do not want.

My current JSR Preprocessor looks something like the following -

````
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

try {

    Random generator = new Random();
        List<String> uuids = new ArrayList<String>();
    int n = 1000;

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/uuids.txt"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            uuids.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }

    int rn = uuids.get(generator.nextInt(n));
    vars.put("some_file", "/files/" + uuids.get(rn) + ".json.gz");
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}```
````

Comment: These are hand picked ids which key into bunch of files. Actually the id is the name of a gz file which I need to POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a little bit wrong because:

1. JSR223 PreProcessor is executed before each request in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)
2. JSR223 PreProcessor is executed by each thread (virtual user)

So I would recommend the following enhancement:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your test plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to it with the following code:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   props.put('uuids', new File('uuids.txt').readLines())
   ```

   this will let you read the file only once and only by one thread.
3. Whenever you want to access a random uuid you can use the following [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function:

   ```
   ${__groovy(props.get('uuids').get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\,props.get('uuids').size())),)}
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks @dimitri-t. I was able to load uuids using the Sampler. Now I am trying to see how I can use the random file selected to be posted as a part of the Request. I need to simulate the following curl call -


`curl -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' --data-binary @my_file.json.gz -v http://host:port/api`

The my_file.json.gz is the random id I need to get by using the groovy function. I do see a FilesUpload tab in the Http Request but not sure how & where to set the same.

Comment: So in File Upload I added the following to File Path and kept the Parameter Name empty and MIME Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  

`${__groovy("/Users/sam/payload/payload_by_uuids/" + props.get('uuids').get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\,props.get('uuids').size())) + "json.gz",)}`

But I get the following error when I try to run the request -

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/sam/payload/payload_by_uuids/f415181a-6112-3219-a4a1-042ce1a83b26.json.gz   (No such file or directory)`

Although the file is present at that location.

Comment: Also if i hardcode the filepath in the File Upload it works.

Comment: I changed the uuids.txt file to have the full path and in the File Uploads in the File Path I did `${__groovy(props.get('uuids').get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\,props.get('uuids').size())),)}` which worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead JMeter's plugin [bzm - Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md)

Just input the CSV filename and it will generate random uuid every time

[image]